# How to write dynamic query to create table with dynamic insert statement from excelsheet?

Tags: mysql

I have following data in my excelsheet

```
|Date     |clntname |clntcode |amt  |
|20170101 |prakash  |7PRF36   |20000|
|20170101 |prakash  |7PRF36   |44000|
|20180310 |prakash  |7PRF36   |20000| 
|20180310 |prakash  |7PRF36   |20000|
|20190601 |prakash  |7PRF36   |20000| 
|20190101 |prakash  |7PRF36   |22500|
```

and i want to write query dynamically which give me output in mysql and i want to create table with insert statement like

```
Create table clntname_clntcode
(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  Client_Code nvarchar(25) NULL,
  Client_Name nvarchar(50) NULL,
  Startup_Date nvarchar(255) NULL,
  Initial_Amt int NULL,
  Dates nvarchar(255) NULL,
  amt int NULL,
)
```

i want to add some additional fields which is not mentioned in excel but i want it in my table the additional field is `Startup_Date,Initial_Amt`

and i want to create insert statement that execute till the records are present in excelsheet and the insert statement which i want to create is as follows:

```
insert into clntname_clntcode values('Client_Code','Client_Name','Startup_Date','Initial_Amt','Dates','amt')
```

i tried to write query but didn't get it how to do it

Comment: Did you try this one?importing excel sheet directly into mysql only. After inserting try to add new columns you mentioned

Comment: sorry but i couldn't get it from PALLAMOLLA SAI

Comment: We can manually import excel sheet data into mysql database. Is that only you want?

Comment: No i want to create a dynamic procedure so when i upload excelsheet, and that procedure will automatic create table and insert all the records that present in my uploaded excelsheet the table which i want to create i have mentioned and query as well a i have mentioned i want to achieve that result i have multiple client records in excelsheet according to that table has to create for each client

Comment: in what language you want to acheive this one (like front end or backend)?

Comment: In front-end i have made a functionality to upload excel and i want to achieve this one in backend in mysql database

Comment: In backend which language you are using?

Comment: for database mysql and for frontend php+html

Comment: you are using php as backend?

Comment: for excution and calling procedure to show my data, yes php

Comment: please can anyone help me to figure out this????

Comment: help me bro PALLAMOLLA SAI

Comment: this link might help? https://phppot.com/php/import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-using-php/

Comment: Have you searched in google?

Comment: i have checked link that given by you but the problem is that i have multiple clients in single sheet let's suppose e.g client one id on excelsheet B1 client name on B2 and next client on C1 and id on C2 and i want query like this "insert into clntname_clntcode values('Client_Code','Client_Name','Startup_Date','Initial_Amt','Dates','amt')" so how i m gonna achieve this?